# How does a Node.js server know when to execute an event dependent on timezone?

Tags: node.js, date, node-schedule

I am creating a calendar. This calendar will have events. The event will be set by the customer. Lets say they want their event to run on 5pm with timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles',

My question if I host a server on heroku or any server for that matter, How can I compare a date with a timezone to the date now?

My guess is I store the date in UTC time, then run a node scheduler and check if this UTC date is less than my current date with timezone?

How would I compare a UTC date with a date today with timezone?

The only thing I found was to store a date with timezone like this

```
console.log(new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', {
    timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles',
  }))
```

which console logs 10/2/2022, 3:38:06 PM

Im confused with how to compare dates with timezones to the current date

Comment: Why can't you just compare 2 UTC dates?

Comment: so 5pm new york is the same UTC as 5pm Los angeles?

Comment: If you work entirely in UTC dates, then all your  server has to know is its own time zone so it can compare the current time to the UTC date of the event to know when to trigger the event.  The reason for converting dates to UTC before you put them in your data store is you only worry about the client time zone at the time the event is created, not when the event is triggered.

Comment: A UTC time is relative to one common timezone (greenwich mean time) so one UTC time is directly comparable to another without doing timezone offsets.   The timezone is applied when you create the UTC time.  So, a 5pm event in Los Angeles would be stored as 12am the next morning UTC time (Los Angeles time must add +7 hours to get UTC time).  And, don't forget, you also have to deal with daylight savings time.

Comment: *so 5pm new york is the same UTC as 5pm Los angeles?* - no, but event created at 5pm Los Angeles should be displayed as 8pm for users in New York.